# Reloading modal every time- when called

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How could I make sure that modal re-loads every time?

I am using `bootstrap : 3.3.2`. I have tried :

```
 $(this).data('bs.modal', null);
```

on the `hidden.bs.modal` but it doesn't work.

Comment: What you want to achieve with that?

Comment: @Petroff I want to unset each field to default. Also, there are images that are played with (lines are drawn). I want to reset each, when the modal reloads.

Comment: Ok, then `hide.bs.modal  This event is fired immediately when the hide instance method has been called.` is your method. Do reset when modal is closed, so the next time when trigger show event everything will be OK. You have to to reset all manually. Twitter bootstrap 3 modals don't have destroy method. They just show/hide the modal. The markup is provided by you. So you have to care about it.

Comment: Edit: I copy wrong method sorry. `hidden.bs.modal  This event is fired when the modal has finished being hidden from the user (will wait for CSS transitions to complete).`

Comment: set all the necessary styles in javascript/jquery inside the function ,then call it whenever you want

Comment: [The built-in remote modal loading feature is deprecated.](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-options) Write your own loading code.